# How to save png copies of ppm images in Python

Tags: python, image, directory, png, ppm

I have a folder full of *ppm* images and I want to save *png* copies of them.

How do I do that?

I've tried executing the following code but nothing happens.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import sys
import os.path

from os.path import isfile,join 
from PIL import Image

target_path = '/Users/lfw/test'
trg = os.listdir(target_path)
count = 0
 for i in trg:
  fullpath = os.path.join(target_path ,i)
  if os.path.isfile(fullpath): 
  im = Image.open(fullpath)
  im.save(str(count) + 'output.png')
  count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have on your desktop a root folder called `test` containing `my_script.py` and a subfolder called `input` where all the ppm files are stored.

You can use the following code to save a png copy of every ppm image.

**my_script.py**

```
import os 
import cv2 
from glob import glob 

cwd = os.getcwd()
input_dir = os.path.join(cwd, "input\\*.ppm")    
ppms = glob(input_dir)   

counter = 1 

for ppm in ppms: 
    cv2.imwrite(str(counter)+".png", cv2.imread(ppm))
    counter += 1
```

**NOTE:** I've written the code in a particular way that let's you *mantain* the old ppm files and creates brand new png copies of the original images. If you want to actually *replace* the ppms with pngs I can edit the answer making it doing the desired job.

Comment: Do this: create a brand new folder on your desktop and call it "test". Put my_script.py in your "test" folder. Now, in the "test" folder create a "input" subfolder and place there all your ppm files. Then finally, open a terminal, navigate to the "test" folder and execute python my_script.py. Does it work this way?

Answer (score 2):

There's no real need to write any Python, you can just use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal - as installed on most Linux distros and available for macOS and Windows:

```
magick mogrify -format png *ppm
```

If you want the output files in a different folder, use:

```
mkdir -p newFolder
magick mogrify -format png -path newFolder *ppm
```

---

If you have many files to do, you can do them in parallel with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel convert {} {.}.png ::: *ppm
```

---

If you use v6 or older of **ImageMagick**, that becomes:

```
mogrify -format png *ppm
```

Comment: It's not the way I need it now, but it's a great way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image 
import glob, os
directory = r'D:\DATASET\...'
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.ppm")):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    im.save(file + ".png")
```